# Injecting Conditional Template string in postgreSQL query causing error

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, database, postgresql

Im trying to set up filtering and sorting in my sql query. The issue Im having I assume is due to syntax constructing the template string since when I test my sql query with static data it is successful. I am new to sql so if im missing any information here that is important for understanding my problem please let me know.

In my request to the server I am sending query values for the `column` and value i want to `filter` by. I am creating a conditional statement to inject into my query that looks like this:

```
const buildFilter = column && filter ? sql`WHERE ${sql(`pipe.${column}`)} = ${sql(`${filter}`)}` : sql``;


const pipelineData = await sql`select pipe.*,
   pipe.updated_at hello,
   prod.details ->> 'manufacturer'      make,
   prod.details ->> 'model'             model,
   prod.details ->> 'model_year'        model_year,
   prod.details ->> 'advertised_price'  price,
   (select first_name || ' ' || last_name from tbl_users where id=pipe.user_id) as user_name,
   (select first_name || ' ' || last_name from tbl_customers where id=lead.customer_id) as customer_name
   from tbl_pipeline pipe
  join tbl_products prod on pipe.product_id = prod.id
  join tbl_leads lead on pipe.lead_id = lead.id
  ${buildFilter}
```

The Error:

```
PostgresError: column "4205fd0a-d1f3-40cc-b91c-d08c88b9947c" does not exist
    at ErrorResponse
```

And when I log `pipe.${column} = ${filter}` I get my expected result which is `pipe.user_id = 4205fd0a-d1f3-40cc-b91c-d08c88b9947c`

For reference this is the query that ultimatly I am trying to build which works when I run in my sql client workbench:

```
select pipe.*,
   pipe.updated_at hello,
   prod.details ->> 'manufacturer'      make,
   prod.details ->> 'model'             model,
   prod.details ->> 'model_year'        model_year,
   prod.details ->> 'advertised_price'  price,
   (select first_name || ' ' || last_name from tbl_users where id=pipe.user_id) as user_name,
   (select first_name || ' ' || last_name from tbl_customers where id=lead.customer_id) as customer_name
   from tbl_pipeline pipe
  join tbl_products prod on pipe.product_id = prod.id
  join tbl_leads lead on pipe.lead_id = lead.id
  WHERE pipe.user_id = '4205fd0a-d1f3-40cc-b91c-d08c88b9947c'
```

Comment: Your question explanation jumps around a lot.  Try re-ordering the logic in the question so things are in sequence.  Basically give us the code in ONE code block so we can see what's being declared when.  Picking pieces doesn't help you or us.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have cleaned up my question a bit. I hope it helps with clarity.

Comment: What programming language and framework is the top code block?  And also, when you say "log", what is your setup for logging?

Comment: The language is Javascript and im working with postgresql. I am running my changes locally and logging into my console.

Comment: Please add "JavaScript" to your tag list.  Also, what framework in JavaScript is this?  There's obviously a special syntax in which this framework uses.  This is relevant because that is where the error is happening.  Either during parsing or during interpolation.  (not the error you're getting in Postgres--that error is meaningless.  But instead, the implicit error in your syntax leading to the end result WHERE clause).  What is likely happening, which you cannot see is WHERE 4205fd0a-d1f3-40cc-b91c-d08c88b9947c = ?

Comment: My educated guess is that your JavaScript framework syntax needs single quotes around the hash value.  Because single quotes are often special characters, you will need to know what the value of a single quote in the entire code stack and walk backwards to figure out how to add the quotes correctly.  Search google with a keyword of "escape characters" (or "escape sequence") in JavaScript and Postgres.

Comment: When I say call stack, here's a guess.  Javascript framework syntax > JavaScript > application layer of JavaScript framework--might be C#, Java, Python, etc., or nothing > driver connecting to Postgres (in some language--JDBC would use Java for example) > Postgres.  So the single quote could change as it travels to Postgres, leading to lack of correct quote character.

Answer (score 1):

The JavaScript framework is not a tag on your question.  This might be because the source code is proprietary to your company, in which case I understand why it's not there.  Without documentation to that Javascript framework and a list of the programming languages that go from client (Javascript framework) to server (Postgres), it's impossible to give you the exact answer, but instead, just help with the understanding on how to solve the issue.

Based on the expected server source code (Postgres) of pipe.user_id = '{hash}', your client source code needs to conform to the original pre-translated version of this.  Because the server code error is missing single quotes, you will need to determine how to change the syntax of this line of code (below) to incorporate single quotes around the value of the filter.  If your code sometimes uses variables and sometimes uses values (as you need here), then you might need additional logic or separate this code from the other.

```
const buildFilter = column && filter ? sql`WHERE ${sql(`pipe.${column}`)} = ${sql(`${filter}`)}` : sql``;
```

Add a single quote before your filter and a single quote after your filter.

Single quotes are often escaped in programming language source code so that when interpolated, the correct value results.  This is sometimes called an escape sequence or escape character.  Because there may be several programming languages from client to server, the single quote might get translated to different characters along the way.

You spoke about logging.  I'm guessing you have another piece of software to test this, rather than perform it in production.  You might have to test a bunch of different scenarios to see what gets interpolated in the call stack.  You might need to escape twice, if one language in the call stack passes output as input to the next language.  For example, if a `\'` is valid in one language, but the next language needs `\\'`, you might need two backslashes in the first language.  A good example is Excel to a text file when exporting.  There are two values to know about.  The source code value and the literal value.  ***Just realize that the literal value as output of one language is the input for the source code of the next language in the call stack.***  But what you have here is input from the original language, which is your JavaScript framework.

Like so:

```
const buildFilter = column && filter ? sql`WHERE ${sql(`pipe.${column}`)} = \' ${sql(`${filter}`)} \'` : sql``;
```

or

```
const buildFilter = column && filter ? sql`WHERE ${sql(`pipe.${column}`)} = \\' ${sql(`${filter}`)} \\'` : sql``;
```

This is likely not correct, but I'm just explaining how you might go about it.

I also apologize for my first comment.  I had no idea what the first code block was and for what programming language.  I don't understand the grammar of the language, and therefore, I don't understand the syntax of the source code you have.

Comment: Thanks for this response, its given me some direction to look in. I should have included javascript in the tags I will add it.

Comment: Anytime.  This is a difficult problem to deal with because the JavaScript framework you are using (or application code) has it's own grammar because it's passing code to Postgres.  It's almost like a compiler.  So you need to deal with escaping a single quote in JavaScript first, if it's inside a string.  Then add any special characters to escape the single quote for the JavaScript framework syntax.  The lower level language (JavaScript) comes first for parsing.  Then predict what the next language needs to understand what the single quote is.  It's challenging.  Good luck!